# How to search numbers (e.g. years) in commit messages with GitAhead?

Tags: gitahead

I noticed that GitAhead (v2.6.1) doesn't seem to index numbers (e.g. years).

Example commit message: "prepare for January 2020 release".

The search terms "message:January" or "message:release" do find this commit, whereas the search term "message:2020" does not.

How can I search for commit messages containing a certain number?